# IntelliJ IDEA can no longer run my Gradle run configurations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

One of my IDEA installations has stopped running my Gradle run configurations.  The run configuration is for a regular Java app submodule in my project (the module is called "server"), and the run configuration is as simple as it can get:

```
Gradle Project:  /path/to/server/build.gradle

Tasks:  run
```

No VM arguments, tool windows or any other configuration.

When I run it, I get this:

[image: IDEA build error: just says Run build]

with no other output.  It is not failing on my other machines that are running the same version of IDEA against the same checkout of the same source repository.

I am running the latest IDEA for OS X, 3.5.  I tried downgrading to 3.4, by deleting my 3.5 app and installing 3.4 from scratch, and I got the same error running my configuration.

I have tried (many times) invalidating the caches and removing the out/ directory.  When everything is recreated, I get the same error.

I've tried deleting the run configuration and recreating it.  Same error.

I've tried creating different Gradle run configurations for other submodules in my project.  Same error when I try to run them.

I *can* switch into any of my submodules and type "gradle run", and they run just fine.  It's only in IDEA that they can no longer run.

Update:  I edited my run configuration, switched to the Logs tab, and enabled "Save console output to file", sending it to /tmp/idea.txt, and got this error:

The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.

It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch:

Java home is different.

Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/user3562927/.gradle/daemon,pid=52404,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]

Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=ec6aa2e2-e5c9-4857-b08b-1e79fa37a332,javaHome=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home,daemonRegistryDir=/Users/user3562927/.gradle/daemon,pid=53135,idleTimeout=60000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]

Not sure why IDEA is not able to show me this information in the "4: Run" pane.

At least I know this is JDK-related now.  I've tried updating my JDK in my project structure, and various other remedies suggested on this site, with no luck yet, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: Is this IDEA installation a different version from the others? This looks like it contains an older version of gradle (I believe there is one bundled in every version). if you use a gradle wrapper (define the task) and use the same version everywhere and import the project again specifying to use the default wrapper, it might work.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all JVMs on my machine and painstakingly switched my project and module SDKs all over to the sole remaining JDK.  No luck.

Then I noticed this little icon in the upper-left corner of the Run pane, which, when clicked, gave me the build output:

[image: build text mode output]

It looks like there are garbage characters in my JVM spec.  The only place it is defined is in  ~/.gradle/gradle.properties, so I deleted that file (even though there were no garbage characters in it).  After that I'm back to the "The newly created daemon process has a different context" error.

After trying many many other things, I finally deleted my project's `.idea` directory and recreated it.  This finally made the problem go away.

JetBrains really needs to get a handle on this problem.  I had to recreate my dictionaries, my code style settings, etc.  The IDE should be handling the presence of multiple JDKs without choking like this.

Comment: wow, even in 2020, this `.idea` directory incompatibilities are causing Gradle wrapper to not run without any errors on the output... glad to find this, deleting `.idea` folder definitely helped!